# Combining @IDClass with @JoinColumn

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This is my sample entity structure
**Parent class**

```
@IDClass(TicketPK.class)
class Ticket {
@Id
int ticket_id;
@Id
Date month;
}
```

**Child entity**

```
@IDClass(FooPK.class)
class Foo {
@Id
int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "Ticket_ID", referencedColumnName = "Ticket_id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "month", referencedColumnName = "month") })
    private Ticket ticket;
}
```

Primary Key for Foo consist of 'id' and 'month'. How do I specify 'month' also as composite key in my Foo entity. Also what would be my FooPK class?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just map the attribute in the entity? I would use embedded ids instead:

```
@Entity
class Foo {
    @EmbeddedId
    FooId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "Ticket_ID", referencedColumnName = "Ticket_id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "month", referencedColumnName = "month") })
    private Ticket ticket;
}

@Embeddable
class FooId {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    int id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    int month;
}
```